# Multiplos environment laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

Como crio vários environment e mudo em tempo de execução o environment que estou usando no laravel 5.5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acordo com a documentação, você poderá criar verificações manuais de qual ambiente está através do método `App::envinroment()`.

Por exemplo:

```
if (App::environment('local')) {
    // Ambiente local
}

if (App::environment(['local', 'staging'])) {
    // Ambiente de Teste!
}
```

Através da variável `APP_ENV`, você poderá alterar o nome do ambiente que deseja utilizar.

Por exemplo:

```
APP_ENV=testing
```

Há ainda uma forma de forçar o `artisan`a rodar com determinada configuração de ambiente, que é através da opção `--env`.

```
php artisan --env=testing
```

Parece que a solução adotadas em algumas versões do Laravel 5.* é sobrescrever manualmente o arquivo `.env` manualmente. Você pode fazer isso no AppServiceProvider, verificando por exemplo se determinado arquivo existe para aplicar as modificações.

Veja:

```
$testing = '.env.testing';

if (File::exists(base_path($testing)) {

   $dotenv = new \Dotenv\Dotenv(base_path(), $testing);
   $dotenv->overload(); 
}
```

**Observação**: `Dotenv\Dotenv` é a classe responsável por carregar os valores do `.env`.